# Unable to get the selected records from EJ2 Multiple selection dropdown

Tags: angular

I am using ej2 angular multi selection check box in my application.
if user opens the multi selection dropdown user can do select and unselect operations at a time.
after doing this action is there any inbuilt method available to get the selected records from multi select dropdown.

Thanks in advance and it will be very big help to me.

```
<ejs-multiselect id='multiselect_checkbox' #checkbox='ngModel'
              [dataSource]='dropDownList.RuleCategory | sortpipe:"Value"' [placeholder]='model.placeholder'
              [fields]='model.checkFields' [mode]='model.mode' [popupHeight]='model.popHeight'
              [filterBarPlaceholder]='model.filterPlaceholder' (change)="getCategoryData1($event)"
              [(ngModel)]="categoryData" (removing)="removeItem($event)" id="rule_category" (actionComplete)="actionComplete($event)"></ejs-multiselect>
```